# How to set height to a child div?

Tags: html, css

i have a div in another div whose height is 48px and position relative. now i have a child div in the div whose height is 48px. i want the child div max-height to be set to 80% and min-height set to 40%. in doing so, the child divs height is just 48px.

Below is the code,

```
<div class="top_div">
    <div class="drawer">
        <div class="menu">
            <header>
                <Svg>
                <button></button>
            </header>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul></div></div></div>


.top_div {
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    align-items: center;
}

.drawer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: $white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 380px;
    top: 55px;
    right: 8px;
    min-height: 40%;
    max-height: 80%;

    header {
        height: 41px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-top: 2px;

        svg {
            margin-left: 16px; 
        }
   }

   ul {
       overflow-x: hidden;
   }

   ::after {
       content: " ";
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 100%;
       left: 83%;
       margin-left: -5px;
       border-width: 14px;
       border-style: solid;
       border-color: transparent transparent $white transparent;
   }
}
```

If i remove position : relative for top_div then it works well but remove the box-shadow for topbar...how can i fix this. I want the box-shadow to be there. or if i keep position:relative for top_div then i want the height of the drawer to be 80%.

How can i fix this. could someone help me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the code into an html document, and set the `position` of your child's div to `relative`. For me this solved the issue, and I got exacly what you want to do.

Try this.

I hope this can help, for me it helped.